# How to mirror two geodatabases on the fly?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase, replication

I'm new to arcgis and its applications.

We have the full suite of arcgis solutions (arcgis server, desktop, arcgis sde)

We have a requirement...

1. geodatabase (A & B)
2. A & B reside on 2 different server but connected via LAN
3. A will be updated
4. B will be a replica of A

May I know what is the best solution to this issue? the geodatabase can be hosted on oracle DB, personal geodatabase or geodatabase file.

I know that arcgistools has the functions to replicate and sync but according to my friend. the synchronization has to been done manually. (creeate a script and execute it periodically.

Is there a way to mirror those 2 geodatabase on the fly?

Comment: ArcSDE supports Enterprise Geodatabases versioning & replication http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Replicas_and_geodatabases/003n000000vp000000/ - question is what database backend are you using? (Oracle?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Replicas and geodatabases**

> An ArcSDE geodatabase can host both child and parent replicas. This
>   enables data to be replicated across multiple geodatabases

[image]

Full Official Documentation

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Replicas_and_geodatabases/003n000000vp000000/

Comment: And it can be scripted as well, right? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000016000000

Comment: hi may i know if there is a solution for sync 2 personal geodatabase

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to mirror the databases "on the fly" using ArcGIS geodatabase replication. You could attempt something like this with DBMS replication but that is not a recommended practice. Best thing to do is set up a scheduled task to run the synchronization (via python script) as frequently as you need.

[Understanding Distributed Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_distributed_data/003n000000ts000000/)

The following facts compare geodatabase replication and DBMS replication:

- Geodatabase replication synchronizes changes from specific ArcSDE
  geodatabase versions. DBMS replication, when used with an ArcSDE
  geodatabase, applies changes across all versions in the geodatabase.
- Geodatabase replication supports all advanced geodatabase objects
  like topologies, relationships, and geometric networks. DBMS
  replication does not know how to properly replicate advanced
  geodatabase objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something simple, you could use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) or [Bittorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) to mirror the databases on the fly. They both operate in realtime using Windows' file snapshot services, so changes get caught. You'll still want a traditional backup, but, if the scale of your project doesn't necessitate using your SDE option, these two can be elegantly simple. Otherwise, I think the other answers here give you your best options.

Comment: This should work, so long as the destination db, the replica, has file-system permissions set to read-only for all users. Otherwise even users just reading the data, not even editing it, open schema locks on the replica side which will cause problems.

Comment: there are many other file-system sync tools as well: owncloud, rsync, MirrorFolder, [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software)